# Android app unable to start activity componentinfo google map v2

Tags: android

i am trying to do this google map v2 tutorial and i run in to a problem 
i did add the google-play-services-lib to my project
runing on emulator v:4.3 APILevel:18 cpu/abi:arm
i never used fragments befor soo i think that may be the root of the problem but i cant be sure
i am geting this error:

> 11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       
> 11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{asaf.workfinder/asaf.workfinder.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class fragment
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>    
>    11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:267)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1895)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at asaf.workfinder.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:13)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     ... 11 more
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:592)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:560)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4738)
>      
>  11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     ... 21 more
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/asaf.workfinder-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/asaf.workfinder-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
>    
>    11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
>    
>    11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:582)
>     
>   11-04 13:35:31.572: E/AndroidRuntime(1375):     ... 24 more

manifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="asaf.workfinder"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <permission
        android:name="asaf.workfinder.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />


    <uses-permission android:name="asaf.workfinder.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

        <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

          <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="my api key" />


        <activity
            android:name="asaf.workfinder.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        />

    <fragment 
          android:id="@+id/asafmap"
          android:layout_below="@+id/tv1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and MainActivity:

```
package asaf.workfinder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View.OnCreateContextMenuListener;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment". Probably a build issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
```

Be sure you added the google_play_services correctly in ur project 
[Set Up Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)

BTW, Google Map V2 doesn't support to run in the emulator to run it in the emulator follow
[this post](http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/english/2012/12/06/how-to-make-android-google-maps-v2-work-in-android-emulator/)

Comment: seems the first few times i added the google_play_services it didnt work right now i just need to get the emulator to support maps v2 thx

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this link....

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/

Add google play services lib and mpas jar file into project...